# Facebooker Connect and Safari 4

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbjs

Seems to be a known problem, but I didn't find the solution.

When your facebook app tries to perform some JS call via loading fb:iframe with JS code, Safari blocks this saying

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL  from frame with URL . Domain, names and protocols must match

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked bugzilla? http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the ChannelUrl in your FB.init() If not set, you might get some of those issues.

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

Also be sure your server is sending out a valid p3p header.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx